# In Django FileField, how to set file.name that contains also random url?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

EDIT
I am trying to modify the name of an uploaded file to include also some url in it. In my case it's the custom "file_url" variable. However the current result is: "filename", but the expected result should be: [http://www.google.com/"filename"](http://www.google.com/%22filename%22)

Here is my View.py:

```
class CreateImage(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    model = models.Image
    serializer_class = serializers.ImageSerializer

    def get_serializer(self, container, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs["context"] = self.get_serializer_context()
        old_filename = self.request.FILES['image'].name
        if self.request.FILES:
            if container == 'products':
                data = self.request.data.copy()
                product_name = data["product_name"]
                file_url = f"{settings.MEDIA_DOMAIN}{container}/"
                new_filename = get_product_new_filename(old_filename, product_name)

                data['image'].name = file_url + new_filename
                kwargs["data"] = data
                return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

And simple model for reference:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

Do you have any idea, how to include given url in the filename? [edit] **it looks like the issue is with "/" sign. Is it possible to inlcude it in the name?**

The workaround, would be to create additional field, say image_url as CharField, and save it there, but maybe there is a way to not duplicate table inputs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the reason to have that url?

Comment: that is good point - what is the reason:). I could not answer the same question, and i decided to insert additional field that stores proper link. Thanks anyway for comment!

Comment: please write your solution for this as an answer so that others can see it